# Index change after using groupby agg

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  Code                             A1    A2  A3 ...   B40
    Time
2000-01-01 00:00:10.730              NaN   1   NaN    NaN
2010-01-01 00:00:12.730              1     2   3      NaN
```

I want to aggregate data every one hour and calculate some stats. I used the following code:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.index.hour)
# computing various stats
grouped = grouped.agg(['std', 'mean', 'skew'])
grouped
```

output is

```
                                    A1                A2      ...  B40      
    Time                           mean std skew  mean std skew
     0                               1    2    0    2    1    9
     1
     .
     .
     .
    1000                              1   2    3    1    0    1
```

The issue is that I am loosing my Time values and getting integer index instead of time. How can I preserve the time with it's initial format. so the out put that I want is  like this:

```
                                     A1                A2    ...   B40      
    Time                           mean std skew  mean std skew
2000-01-01 00:00:00.00             1    2    0    2    1    9
.
.
.
2010-01-01 00:01:00.00              1   2    3    1    0    1
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for same output use `floor`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.index.floor('h')).agg(['std', 'mean', 'skew'])
```

Another solution with `resample`, but it create completely time range data:

```
grouped = df.resample('h').agg(['std', 'mean', 'skew'])
```